# Flutter Login -> HomePage -> Logout problem

Tags: flutter, dialog

I am trying to create a Login Page with a function to check if username and password is correct, if so, navigate to HomePage, on the other hand,  show an alert.  Problem arises after navigated to HomePage, then logout and return to Login Page, when the alert screen pops up upon login failed, pressed the Dismiss button, then the app crashes with exception:

The following _CastError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Null check operator used on a null value

Here are my codes:

Login Page:

```
void checkValidLogin(context, _username, _password) async {
  bool response = false;
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), (){
    if (_username.toUpperCase() == 'TONY' && _password == '888') {
      response = true;
    };
  });
  if (response == true) {
    //Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => homePage()));
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => homePage()));
  }else{
    showMessage(context, 'Login Fail', 'Invalid Username/Password!');
  };
}
```

Home Page:

```
IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.logout,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MyApp()));
            },
          ),
```

Show Alert:

```
void showMessage(context, _title, _content) {
  showPlatformDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) => BasicDialogAlert(
      title: Text(_title),
      content:
      Text(_content),
      actions: <Widget>[
        BasicDialogAction(
          title: Text("Dismiss"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_CastError was thrown while handling a gesture: Null check operator used on a null value` generally is thrown when you are trying to use `context` of a deactivated widget.

In your case, the problem in the following line:

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MyApp()));
```

You are navigating to `MyApp` which contains `MaterialApp`, so there will be two `MaterialApp`s, because of which the `Navigator` works incorrectly. Later when you click "Dismiss" button `Navigator.pop(context)` is poping the `LoginPage` onstead of closing the dialog box. When you press the button again, it tries to use `context` of the deactivated `LoginPage` and the error is thrown.

Therefore, you have to update the function of `IconButton`:

```
IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.logout,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        onPressed: (){
          Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginPage()));
        },
      ),
```